# How can I correct indentation in namespace block using `indent` utility in linux

Tags: c++, linux, indentation

(I've posted this question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and marked off-topic. Moderator suggested to post question at SO)

I'm using `indent` to correct indentation. Everything is fine except indent in namespace block.

I have sample codes:

```
$ cat test2.cc
#include <iostream>

namespace API
{
void f ()
{
    std::cout << "f() called" << std::endl;
}
}
```

But after running `indent` I got:

```
$ indent -st -bl -bli0  -i 4 -c 4 -kr -nce -bls test2.cc
#include <iostream>

namespace API
{
    void f()
^^^^<=== I don't want these indentation
    {
        std::cout << "f() called" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I don't want first indentation of namespace block and hard to find any related indent option (it's very complicated). How can I work it out? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indent` is designed to format C code. It's not really aware of C++ syntax, such as `namespace`.

I'd suggest using [`clang-format`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html), which is a C++ formatter.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I'll check `clang-format`.